# Problems in data frame for re using it in R

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I am trying to create an application which works with `csv` files . When i call `read.csv("Filename.csv")` it stores the data in to the data frame name `aw_df`.
I want to check condition for headers and rename the existing headers with a row present in the dataframe.

code:
Server.r

```
if (aw_df[2,]$Time == "Timestamp1")
{
headers <- aw_df[2,]
aws_df <- aw_df[-c(1,2,3),]
colnames(aws_df) <- as.character(unlist(headers))
}
```

It changes the header of the file but while performing any operations to it like agg functions

`aws_df <- aggregate(list(aws_df[,2:12]), list( aws_df$classmt ), mean)`

It throws Warning stating `NA`

> Warning in mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
>
> argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

And data frame returns `NA` values.

1.How do i fix this??
2. What is the reason behind this problem.

I have tried using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` as well but same result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You create a dataframe called `aws_df`, but then set column names on `aw_df`. Did you mean to change the column names on `aws_df`?

Comment: @Marius `aw_df` is already created prior . I want to store that data into new data frame with new headers . Or only store the values skipping first 4 rows from `aw_df` dataframe to `aws_df` dataframe

Comment: It might actually be better to just read the csv again once you've extracted the header info, with `read.csv(..., skip = 4)`. That way the columns should be automatically set to the appropriate types.

Comment: `aws_df[] <- lapply(aws_df, type.convert)`

Comment: @Marius . I was planning to do the same but it will take lot of time for large data set file. If am not wrong.

Comment: @Roland What will the above function will do?

Comment: Looking at `help("type.convert")` I see you don't even need the loop. `aws_df <- type.convert(aws_df)` is sufficient. `type.convert` is the function `read.table` and co. use internally to convert imported data to the appropriate data type.